# проблемы с msys2

Tags: c++, linux, windows, msys2

В общем проблемы такие. установил я библиотеки mingw-w64 gstreamer plugin good ugly bad. но в `mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config.exe --list-all | grep gstreamer` выводит только `bad` из плагинов, ну ещё и `base`. потом я не могу скомпилировать проект. вот что пишет.

```
/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++.exe -DWINDOWS_VERSION radio.cpp talk.cpp talk_report.cpp -I. $(LIBS_WINDOWS) -o radio.exe
make: *** [makefile:17: windows] Error 1
```

так. мне удалось скомпилировать. теперь он просит библиотеки. я создал отдельный каталог и туда программу перенес. и начал переносить каждую библиотеку, которую запрашивает. но теперь такая надпись.
`error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: у gst-plugins-{good,ugly} и нет собственных `pkg-config`-файлов...

Comment: @Fat-Zer хорошо, спасибо. а как насчет последнего. я только что добавил запись в вопросник.

Comment: а это звучит уже как какая-то виндовая проблема... тут я не подскажу... сперва я бы начал копать с того, где gstreamer ищет свои плагины...

Comment: @Fat-Zer всё. я уже разобрался. но теперь новые ошибки. теперь не запускается, потому что не может найти иконки.

Comment: сколько не пытался работать с нативным mingw - sdk поставленная в wine работает лучше)